# MySQL Select All WHERE Statement - Need Help

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to put together some coding to enable foreman to find the bricklayer they need to use for jobs in different towns and depending on the type of bricklaying to be done.

I setup a MySQL Database Table called USERS which has all the details for each user (which include the people looking for the bricklayers and the bricklayers themselves), such as userid, first_name, last_name etc. There are 7 main types of bricklayers being: traditional, architectural, pave, slab, routing, plank, decorative and thins. I may have to add more later on.

I have another table (or plan on setting it up) called POSTCODES. This has about 1000 town postcodes, a column for each type of bricklayer. The userid of each bricklayer to be used for each postcode is shown in each of the bricklaying types. Only 1 bricklayer for each bricklayer type is to be shown.

For example the Postcodes table columns and data looks like this (or will):

```
Postcode, traditional, architectural, pave, slab, routing, plank, decorative, thins
1003, 21, 34, 78, 98, 34, 77, 21
1004, 56, 45, 35, 98, 78, 23, 12
etc
```

The numbers 21, 34, 78, 98, 34, 77, 21 are the userid's for the bricklayers that are the ones to be used for the different postcodes. For example if I need a thins bricklayer in postcode 1003, the userid for the bricklayer we need would be 21. If I need a pave bricklayer in postcode 1003 then I would need 78. If I need a slab bricklayer in postcode 1004 then I would need 98.

To pull the records of the bricklayer they need to use I was going to use a Select All from Users WHERE userid.users = ???? This is where I got stuck? Basically I need to be able to pull the data for the relevant bricklayer user. In the above examples I would need to pull the data for either user 21, 78 or 98.

The form the people will fill in to find the right bricklayer is as follows:

What type of bricklayer do you need?
Radio button or drop down menu with options: 
traditional, architectural, pave, slab, routing, plank, decorative, thins

What postcode is the job in?
Then they enter the postcode.

The next page will show (hopefully :) the details of the person they need to contact and use.

Comment: So there can only ever be a single bricklayer of each type in any given postcode? This doesn't seem a very well designed database.

Comment: Yep only one per type per postcode.. So will have 7 bricklayers for each postcodes.. Ideas?

Comment: Basically it is not a list of available bricklayers to choose from but a list of the ones they must use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it you do not have much experience with PHP OR MySQL. This is SQL 101. It also sounds like your Schema is a complete mess. This is what you should have (basic pseudo code):

```
TABLE users (
id PK,
name,
...
);

TABLE types (
id PK,
name
);

TABLE postcodes (
code PK,
location_name,
...
);

TABLE bricklayers (
user_id FK to users,
type_id FK to types,
code FK to postcodes
) PK (type_id, code);
```

Now, The PK in bricklayers will limit the number of types of bricklayers to each postalcode to 1. This means you will only get one of each type per postalcode.

To get a list of users who are bricklayers in a specific postalcode, you run:

```
SELECT * FROM bricklayers WHERE code = {POSTALCODE};
```

This will give you the Type_id and the User_id of all bricklayers. You can couple the select with a join so you pull the information from each table instead of just the IDs. But this should get you where you are going.

Comment: Mmmm.. Thank you and little over my head.. yes newbie with both MySQL and PHP.. is it that obvious :) but slowly learning.. Using DW and it does a lot of the SQL basic coding that I normally need (which is not really very much).. Anyway still a little confused..

Comment: You think that's how it "should" be done?! A tabled called `Types` is really vague. Why isn't `Type.name` a key i.e. won't different `Types` with the same `name` be really confusing? Shouldn't the key in the `Brickayers` table be `(type_id, code)`? I don't see anything in the spec to suggest that the same bricklayer cannot perform more than one type for the same postcode (and common sense suggests this is a likely scenario).

Comment: @onedaywhen: As for the `types` table, an integer is generally a better choice for a key, and `name` could simply be associated with a unique index to exclude duplicates.

Comment: @Andriy M: "an integer is generally a better choice for a key" -- I disagree: the two industry standard identifiers I've used so far today (ISO 3166 and ISO 4217) are both fixed-width text, both are excellent in practise and would be no better (perhaps worse) if replaced using integer values.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Fair enough. But that's where my 'generally' fits in, I think, unless I've been misunderstanding the word's meaning all this time. Your string keys are both short and fixed-width, they are no compare to the type identifiers used in the OP's case.

Comment: @Andriy M: I think you are using 'generally' to imply that the most commonly used type for surrogate or artificial keys is integer, and that would be fair enough. But if you consider the properties of a good key and that the majority of popular industry standard keys (ISBN, EAN, VIN) are not integer, I find little evidence that 'integer is better', generally or otherwise.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Alright, I admit that I have overgeneralised. What I meant was, 'in an RDBMS, an integer is generally a better choice for a key'. I didn't mean to say that it is a generally better choice all over the world. Basically, the question is, what should you choose as a key for an entity? should it be its name or its code? One can argue that `types.name` can easily be a code too. I maintain that it is a poor choice for its own code. An integer is better from a mere fact that an RDBMS can easily provide you with a unique value, you'd just have to declare the column as auto-incrementing.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I mean, an integer *code* is particularly better than a string *code*, because you can auto-increment it. But also it's better than the name, because it's shorter too.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use **cdburgess**'s solution. But if you still wanted to use your scheme, you can use query like this

```
Select * from Users WHERE userid.users IN ( 
    SELECT concat_WS(',', traditional, pave, decorative) as uid FROM `postcodes` WHERE postcode=1003
)
```

add *GROUP BY uid* if you need to search over more then one postcode at a time

Comment: Since I'm not an active MySQL user, I can't be 105% sure, but I think using `CONCAT_WS` here is out of place. The function produces a *string value*, not a *list of integer values*. It's true that the contents of the string would look as a list of values, but that would still be a character string. Your IN expression is effectively `IN ('21,78,77')`, which in my opinion is not the same as `IN (21,78,77)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry if I am a bit daft but still don't really know what to do to solve it?